# How to pass URL with data from javascript instead of ui-sref in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using ui-sref which passes an id to given url  page.But I want the same id and url to be passed from controller JS file rather than HTML.
HTML:

```
<button   ui-sref="Followup({patient:patientid.id})">
        OK  </button>
```

Is it possible to pass the above id and url from Controller get the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-click` like following:

```
<button ng-click="followup(patient)">
        OK  </button>
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.followup = function (patient){
    $state.go('Followup', {patient:patient.id} );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
<button ng-click="go()">   OK  </button>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.go = function (patient){
    $state.go('Followup', {patientid:patient.id} );
}
```

I don't know `patientid.id` is correct or not in your question, so I supposed that we have a patient object and we want to navigate to next page with parameter as patient id.

Comment: If it works fine, kindly select as best answer as there is no other answer yet.. Thanks for the up vote.